# Print array with different deep

Tags: scala, recursion, casting

I have this function in Scala:

```
def printA(A: Array[_]): Unit = {
    if (A.isInstanceOf[Array[Int]]) A.foreach(t => println(t))
    else A.foreach(a => printA(a))
  }
```

I don't know, how to fix this error, that *printA(a)* is *Any*. The function accepts input *Array[_]*

Thanks, guys!

Comment: What would be the expected Output for `printA(Array[String]("foo", "bar"))`?

Comment: I would avoid having that signature in the first place, rather have your own nested list ADT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe, it is better to check an element instead of an array?

```
  def printA(array: Array[_]): Unit = {
    array.foreach {
      case i: Int => println(i)
      case arr: Array[_] => printA(arr)
      case unknown => sys.error("Unsupported element: "+unknown) 
    }
  }
```